# Can VSCode Search automatically check camel case version of snake case words and vice versa?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The codebase I work in uses `snake_case` as a variable naming convention for our backend and `camelCase` for our front end. As a result, to get the full picture of the lifecycle of a variable, I always need to run two searches!

Is there a way that when I initiate a search, eg) I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, then type `some_random_variable`, that VSCode can automatically also check for `someRandomVariable`, and vice versa, including all the results in the same results pane?

If it's not baked in anywhere, is there some way I could write an extension that hooks into search and does this?

Comment: you can always write your own search command or write a command that reads the clipboard and transform the content (the snake case variable) to a regex `snake_case|snakeCase` and put result back in clipboard so you can do ctrl-c => keycombo2camel => ctrl+v, and you can combine these commands with MultiCommand extension and connect a key binding to this multi-command